# What is the most cited paper of all time?

Tags: publications, citations

There was recently a talk at my university of someone who wrote the most cited paper in the top journal of my field. Something like that is usually easy to look up for a single journal, but it made me wonder which would be the most cited paper published in any scientific journal (conference proceedings also count) until now?

Comment: My money is on the bible or something similar.

Comment: Raw numbers are nearly meaningless (if you are after relevance) as some field put out many times more articles than others, without actually moving forward more. As an anecdots, it's a nice measure nonetheless.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

[Nature put out a list](http://www.nature.com/news/the-top-100-papers-1.16224) recently of the most cited papers in Web of Science.

At the top, with more than 300k citations, was a methods paper:

Protein measurement with the folin phenol reagent. Lowry, O. H., Rosebrough, N. J., Farr, A. L. & Randall, R. J. J. Biol. Chem. 193, 265–275 (1951).

Comment: Also of note - the second paper on the list (213k citations) has just a single author...

Comment: @Floris: and it mentions cleavage